# Does the following situation needs synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-synchronization

I have a thread which enables and disables a button in certain random time, if the button clicked when it is enabled an action performed will be executed which will change the image of the button. I am concerned about the synchronization here. Suppose the button is about to get disable and got clicked, so now both threads will execute one to disable it and other to change the image. How should I synchronize this?

Comment: If it needs how should I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Java GUI toolkits (be it Swing, Apache Pivot, JavaFX, AWT, SWT, Android...) are single-threaded. This means that all listeners will always fire in the same thread. So:

- no, you don't need to perform any kind of synchronization,
- yes, you need to take care so that disabling and enabling the button happens in the gui thread (wahetever it's called). The exact code is toolkit-specific.

Comment: AWT is notoriously  *not* single threaded and has synchronized all over the place. When designed it had some ideas to be able to operate from multiple threads, although that's practically not achievable.

Comment: Are you saying that my GUI class should be the actionListener. Currently I have created other action listener class which will change the image in its actionperformed. A separate thread which is toggling the button. But at some moment both the run method and the action performed will share the same button object on which they have to operate. @bestsss

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to understand your point. I am not a experienced programmer. Had I made my question clear or should I eloborate more. I just want that my actionperformed method should be finished before the thread proceeds in execution @bestsss

Comment: Well, my answer is: don't change the button in a different thread, because it's an error. You can't fix it. When you fix it, your other problem will go away.

Comment: I added the code in the thread which is changing the state of the button after sleeping for some time in a synchronized block. Also made the action performed to synchronize on the button so that the problem of RACE wont occur. Hope this help anyone.

Comment: @AmeyJain: so, you ignored my answer and bestss's comments - and your code is wrong (prone for all kinds of synchronization errors). Hopefully the application is not built for an actual client.

Comment: @fdreger : I am not able to figure out how I can do everything in that single thread. I explain the whole situation here : I have a array of 50 buttons. I have assigned a thread a to each button. Each thread disable its button -> sleeps for random time and enable the button back again. While the button is in enable state, if a click is made on it I have to increase the count(count of successful hits). I have create a actionlistner class for this which will increase the count, change the state of the button which is clicked so the user is aware that he clicked the button.

Comment: @fdreger: While the action listener is changing the state of a button to the intermediate state I dont want its thread to also wake up and disable the button at the same time. So why synchronization is not needed here?